# How to make an egress access rule in boto

Tags: python, cloud, boto, aws-security-group

I have been trying to add access rules to a security group "test". Below is the code that i have been using:

```
web = conn.create_security_group('test', 'couch_db')
web.authorize('tcp', 1, 65535, '0.0.0.0/0')
web.authorize('tcp', 5984, 5984, '0.0.0.0/0')
```

When I run the above commands, a new security group named "test" gets created, with two specified INGRESS rules. However, i want my second rule (with port :5984) to be of EGRESS type or EGRESS directed. Could anyone please help me with this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for you:

```
web.authorize_security_group_egress('test', 'tcp', from_port=5984, to_port=5984, cidr_ip='0.0.0.0/0')
```

Comment: I tried this but i guess the below mention error:

AttributeError: 'SecurityGroup' object has no attribute 'authorize_security_group_egress'

Comment: It's not a method on the security group; it's a method on the connection.